# SQL Server : why are there no rows found?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I use this query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 
     f.name as f_firm_name 
FROM Firm f 
WHERE f.id_city = '73041' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS 
ORDER BY f.name ASC
```

I get these results:

```
f_firm_name
--------------------------------
 SKY  LINE STUDIO
 АНТИКВАРНЫЙ САЛОН
 БИЗОН УЛЬЯНОВСК
 ВЕРТЕКС ЗАО
 ВОЗРОЖДЕНИЕ+
 ВОЛГАСПЕЦТЕХНОЛОГИИ
 ГП СЕРВИС
 Данилов А.Б.ИП
 ИНИКОМ
 ИП МАЛАШИН В.Б.
 ИП СУЛАГАЕВ АНДРЕЙ

(20 row(s) affected)
```

But if I use this query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 
     f.name as f_firm_name 
FROM Firm f 
WHERE f.id_city='73041'
  AND f.name LIKE 'ВЕРТЕКС ЗАО%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS 
ORDER BY f.name ASC
```

I get these results:

```
f_firm_name
-----------------
(0 row(s) affected)
```

Why am I getting `0 rows` if in the first query I get `f.name` and use that result to search in the second query?

Comment: Does `LIKE N'ВЕРТЕКС ЗАО%'` work? If so what is the database default collation? Also what is the datatype of the column anyway?

Comment: I get the correct result with SQL Server 2012. Which collation is your database created with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible, the first character in `f_firm_name` - is a space.

So try this one -

```
SELECT TOP 20 f_firm_name = f.name  
FROM dbo.Firm f 
WHERE f.id_city = '73041'
    AND LTRIM(f.name) LIKE 'ВЕРТЕКС ЗАО%' --<--
        COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS 
ORDER BY f.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your database's default collation does not support the characters in the string literal and they are being lost.

Under my default collation `SELECT 'ВЕРТЕКС ЗАО'` returns `??????? ???`

If the column is `nvarchar` use `LIKE N'ВЕРТЕКС ЗАО%'`

If it is `varchar` use

```
LIKE CAST(N'ВЕРТЕКС ЗАО%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS AS VARCHAR(50))
```

as this prevents an implicit cast and is sargable.

Comment: column varchar, query with `LIKE CAST(N'ВЕРТЕКС ЗАО%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS AS VARCHAR(50))` not work... in result i get 0 rows